# Cassandra servers running on Kubernetes Cluster?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, cassandra, containers

Dear Cassandra Admins,

I am thinking if Cassandra is appropriate to be installed on Kubernetes Cluster, as I have never implemented that way before.
I appreciate it if you could share some thoughts ? Here are my questions:

1. I know there exist solutions to install Cassandra on K8s platforms. But in terms of "Pros v.s. Cons", is Kubernetes a really a good platform for Cassandra servers to be installed (assume I need to install Cassandra servers) ?
2. If I want to install Cassandra in "on-prem" Kubernetes cluster(NOT public cloud like Azure, AWS or Google), what "on-prem" Kubernetes solutions you choose? For example:

- OpenShift
- Charmed Kubernetes (I think it’s from Ubuntu)
- HPE Ezmeral
- Vanilla K8S (complete open-source)
- Minikube
- Microk8s,
  Any others K8s solution you choose?

I appreciate you could share insights and thoughts !

Answer (score 3):

> If I want to install Cassandra in "on-prem" Kubernetes cluster(NOT
> public cloud like Azure, AWS or Google), what "on-prem" Kubernetes
> solutions you choose?

Minikube, MicroK8s and other are not for production usage if you setting for just development option you can use any.

If you are setting up for Production grade you can use the [Kops](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops), [kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/12/04/production-ready-kubernetes-cluster-creation-with-kubeadm/) etc.

> I know there exist solutions to install Cassandra on K8s platforms.
> But in terms of "Pros v.s. Cons", is Kubernetes a really a good
> platform for Cassandra servers to be installed (assume I need to
> install Cassandra servers) ?

Yes, good option in terms of Pros you can manage things easily, and scale them as per need.

You might also need to focus on regular backup, monitoring and logging part or server it's not just setup so with K8s setup you have need log backup, database backup things needs to be takecare.

Read this nice article : https://medium.com/flant-com/running-cassandra-in-kubernetes-challenges-and-solutions-9082045a7d93